# Getting HTTP error 500.0 While using ASP.net core project

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

While I trying to make a web APP using .net core This error comes up.
But I have no Error in my code

*.csproj FILE
added here

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>InProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup> 
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.App" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity" version="2.2.0  " />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design" Version="2.2.0" PrivateAssets="All" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Design" Version="1.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.Core" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="2.2.4" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="2.2.4">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <Folder Include="Areas\Admin\Controllers\Views\Category\" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Please also show your code, what you have done so far.

Comment: @AsifRaza I added my code above, please...Thank you

Comment: If you look in the Application errors in the Windows event logs, there should be an error message that tells you what the problem is.

Comment: 500.0 means unhandled exceptions in your code, so spend some time on https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/error-handling?view=aspnetcore-2.2